# How to get ID3 tags for media files on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mp3, id3-tag

I need some help.
The situation looks like this:
I can get list of media files (mp3s, m4as, m4vs an so on) with link to the file (looks like:

```
http://10.0.1.1/Media/Files%20Folder/File%20Itself.m4v
```

So I get an array consisting of links to these files.

I need to display these items in UITableView with corresponding tags (Genre, Artist etc.) and most importantly, album art (it's embedded in file).

How can I fetch that information? If possible, without loading whole media file.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [class for this](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/old-projects/tree/master/metadataRetriever)

It's called metadataRetriever. It returns an array of the

- artist,
- song,
- and album

as NSStrings (in that order)

It's really fast and is safe for synchronous use.

One caveat, it doesn't work for `.m4a's` because the id3 info for `.m4a's` is different.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [`AVURLAsset`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) along with the method [`-loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Also note that the docs say

> AVAsset and other classes provide their metadata “lazily” (see AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading), meaning that you can obtain objects from those arrays without incurring overhead for items you don’t ultimately inspect.

So I'm guessing you won't run into problems of loading the whole file.

Comment: Seems like it's iOS4 only. I'm also writing iPad version, guess I'll have to go some other way. Thanks for showing the easy way,  tho.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`AVMetadataItem`](http://ahttps://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/finding_metadata_values) API:

```swift
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)

assert(asset.isReadable)

let artwork = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: asset.metadata, filteredByIdentifier: .commonIdentifierArtwork).first?.dataValue
let artist = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: asset.metadata, filteredByIdentifier: .commonIdentifierArtist).first?.stringValue
let title = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: asset.metadata, filteredByIdentifier: .commonIdentifierTitle).first?.stringValue
let albumName = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: asset.metadata, filteredByIdentifier: .commonIdentifierAlbumName).first?.stringValue
let duration = asset.duration.seconds
```